# tcsh: how can we display the body of a foreach loop in history

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, tcsh, csh

I see that history doesn't display the body of loops. Is there a way to show them?

```
san: cd /tmp/test
san: touch abc
san: touch def
san: ls
abc   def
san: foreach file ( `ls` )
foreach? echo "File is $file"
foreach? end
File is abc
File is def
san: history | tail -6
   509  9:49    cd /tmp/test
   510  9:49    touch abc
   511  9:49    touch def
   512  9:49    ls
   513  9:49    foreach file ( `ls` )
   514  9:50    history | tail -6
```

History doesn't show the command `echo "File is $file"`

***Update:***

This is solved in new version, see Steve Parker's answer

```
> mkdir /tmp/test
> cd /tmp/test
> touch abc
> touch def
> ls
abc  def
> foreach file (`ls`)
foreach? echo "File is $file"
foreach? end
File is abc
File is def
> history | tail -6
    55  13:09   touch def
    56  13:09   ls
    57  13:09   foreach file ( `ls` )
    58  13:09   echo "File is $file"
    59  13:09   end
    60  13:09   history | tail -6
> tcsh --version
tcsh 6.18.01 (Astron) 2012-02-14 (x86_64-unknown-linux)
```

Comment: I am using exactly the same version 6.18.01, but history is not showing commands inside foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ability came to tcsh at version 17.01, so my tcsh:
propmt> tcsh --version
tcsh 6.17.00 (Astron) 2009-07-10 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec

Does not allow this, but the very next version would support it.

https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/compare/TCSH6_17_00...TCSH6_17_01 <- look under "Files changed" tab and look toward the bottom for line 5019 of the tcsh.man file.